# mango query: dynamic parameter

Tags: pouchdb

I need to make a mango query with PouchDB, passing a value to the find() method.

This code works fine (return data):

```
  getGroups(idFamily) {
    return this.database.find({
       selector: {'type': 'group', 'idFamily': 7},
       fields: ['_id', 'idGroup', 'idFamily', 'description'],
       use_index: 'indice-por-tipo-familia'
     }).then((result)=> {
       return result.docs;        
     }).catch((err)=> {
       console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

But this code doesn't work, empty result (passing parameter idFamily into selector)

```
  getGroups(idFamily) {
    return this.database.find({
       selector: {'type': 'group', 'idFamily': idFamily},
       fields: ['_id', 'idGroup', 'idFamily', 'description'],
       use_index: 'indice-por-tipo-familia'
     }).then((result)=> {
       return result.docs;        
     }).catch((err)=> {
       console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

**idFamily** is type Number (parameter and datatype in document)

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'd guess that you have a bug elsewhere in your code. Try assigning the query to an object and logging it before passing to find.

Comment: solved adding this:


selector: {'type': 'group', 'idFamily': Number(idFamily)},